# Page not found in IIS, but it's there

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I have just installed IIS on Windows Server 2008. If I go to `localhost`, the default page is displayed, so the web server is ok.

I have added a folder with a page in it in the `\inetpub\wwwroot` directory. The full path to the page is then `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.html`.

I have restarted the services but if I navigate to `localhost/folder/file.html` I get a `404 file not found error`.

Obviously I have forgotten something simple, but what is it? :)

Comment: Check error log, you will find what exactly it is searching

Comment: @Sai It is searching that exact file: `GET /folder/file.html - 80`

Comment: I think this is from access log, there will be error log, whenever it fails...!

Comment: @Sai Uhm, weird.. That's the only log file I have..

Comment: Check this, http://forums.iis.net/t/1189242.aspx?IIS+7+HTTP+Error+Log+Location

Comment: what are the permissions on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\ ?

Comment: @FrankThomas For the purposes of this test, Allow to all and for all users.

Comment: I would recommend playing with user permissions if I remember correctly I had an issue with IUser or IIS_user that not being set properly and received the same message.

Comment: most of the time, anonymous accounts are not part of the "everyone" group, so make sure you have IUser or Anonymous permitted to read the files.

Comment: @FrankThomas Anonymous logon is also in the users who are allowed to read the files in the folder :(

Comment: I am having the same issue, can't get it working.  I created a Windows account IUSER_IIS, gave him full permissions on the app directory, set app identity to that user, and created an app pool with that identity, set app to use the app pool.  It can read a simple .HTML file, but I get HTTP 404 on Default.aspx.  Any ideas?  Further details you need?

Comment: If your using Visual Studio's publishing, make sure you've actually published it or it'll give a 404.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone that run into this and don't find the other suggestions effective, also check that Windows is displaying file name extensions. Open Windows Explorer, click "View" in the top bar and then check "File name extensions".

I found that my file was actually named index.html.txt even though it was displaying index.html prior to checking the above setting.

Comment: Thank you. I change this setting on every computer I used but didn't think about it when setting up a server. That fixed it

Comment: Out the box, I always turn that on for every computer I deal with or support. What planet MS are on when they made it "off" by default is baffling.

Comment: Haha! I came here looking for answers, and what did I do?  I mispelled the domain name in the site binding.  doh!

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem.

Observe your path: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.html`.

Ensure that:

- The file name extension you are requesting (in this case, `.html`) is not being blocked by IIS.
- The directories along the path you are requesting (in this case, `folder`) are not being blocked by IIS.

If you are on Windows 8/ Windows 10, you can check those two things in the IIS Manager desktop application.

Here is how:

1. Open the IIS Manager. You can type it in the Windows search bar.
2. In the file tree in the 'Connections' box, select the root of web application.
3. In the Features View that appears in the middle of the screen, select `Request Filtering`.
4. In the `File Name Extensions` tab, ensure that `.html` does not have the value `false`.
5. In the `Hidden Segments` tab, ensure that NONE of the folders in your path (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.html`) are listed.

NOTE: If you cannot see the `Request Filtering` tool, you may not have enabled all of the IIS features. Search for 'Turn off windows features' on your machine. In the Windows Features manager, select all of the boxes in `Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services` and select the box `Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Consoles`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before - I had to set the username and password in again at Anonymous Authentication and it worked perfectly. You can also switch on Detailed errors at Error Pages in IIS to give more info.

Comment: What did you reset the username and password to?

Comment: It was a domain account which was part of Admin and IIS users. All I did was put the details in again.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- Find the **Authentication Configuration** (Anonymous, Basic, Windows, ...)
- Based on the Authentication configuration, check that the account accessing the file (Anonymous, IUSR, SYSTEM, Authenticated Users, ...) has enough **NTFS permissions**
- Check if the file extension is not filtered in **Request Filtering**
- Check if the file extension is explicitly declared in **MIME types**

Comment: Tried to share an .appinstaller file, and need to add it to the MIME types.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. My issue was that I accidentally installed another instance of DNN to the same SQL database. I restored a backup of my database to a new database then pointed the config file to the new database. Then both instances worked great.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS Connections pane, click on the Sites node and check the Status column on the right. In my case, the Default Web Site was stopped and was giving me 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and more. Not only would the html pages not show, but also the images. I noticed the MIME types was not listed in my new computer under the IIS settings and went in and added all the services I could find under Windows Features for IIS. I know its the shotgun approach, and one of those is responsible for the MIME but everything started working correctly once I did this.